# jsf and text based browser

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, htmlunit, lynx

I have the following problem:
We developed a web project using JSF. In many facelets the init()-Method of the action class, that fills the backing bean with data, is called via

```
<f:metadata>
<f:event listener="#{theActionClass.init}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
```

It works fine as long as you use a normal browser like firefox, chrome or even the eclipse browser. But when using a text-based browser like lynx (or using htmlUnit or wget) it seems as the init() method is not called anymore. The data the init() fills into the backing bean is not there and it is not displayed in the text-based browser (but clicking in firefox shows me the data).

For example:

```
<div class="layout1">#{text['somethingFromPropertyFile']}
</div>
<div class="layout2">
<h:outputText value="#{backingBean.someStringValue}" />
</div>
```

Using firefox displays the text from the property file as well as the content of someStringValue in the backing bean. Using a text-based browser only displays the content of the first div-box. 
Has anyone an idea what goes wrong here or how I can fix this so that it works with text-based browsers as well? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you used the right request URL? Symptoms indicate that `FacesServlet` is simply not been invoked and thus the browser is obtaining the raw XHTML source code instead of the produced HTML output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the request URL should be correct and the produced output is HTML. I found that forcing #{theActionClass.init()} in the beginning of the content of the facelet fixes the problem so init actually gets called, but it still appears like this cant be the correct solution for this problem. I am still wondering why the call via preRenderView does not work using a text-based browser.

Comment: update: replacing the event-tag preRenderView  with  `<f:viewAction action="#{theActionClass.init}" />` seems to fix the problem. We found a hint on your blog, so thanks!